# Drop multiple tables at once in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to drop a few tables at once on a ClickHouse cluster. As example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.log_null, default.null_view
```

I get the error:

```
Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 39 (','): , default.null_view. Expected one of: NO DELAY, end of query, INTO OUTFILE, SETTINGS, ON, FORMAT, SYNC (version 21.3.13.9 (official build))
```

What is the correct syntax if such action is supported?

Comment: No such syntax. And no plans to implement such feature because of inconsistent abstraction.

Comment: @DennyCrane You can post it as an answer.